# Diagonalization problem - Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Considering the fallowing square matrix: **A**, **B** and **P**, (det **P** $ \neq0$), and the given expression:

$P^{-1}AP = B$

If $v$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$ from B, which is eigenvector $w$ from A corresponds to the same eigenvector?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried using the equation that defines an eigenvector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $v$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$ for matrix $B$,

$$ P^{-1}APv = Bv = \lambda v$$

Then multiply by $P$ on the left.

$$ A(Pv) = \lambda (Pv)$$.

So, $Pv$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$ for matrix $A$

Comment: This is a problem statement question showing no effort.  We discourage answering those.